# Image target can only be detected in a limited field of view on hololens 1

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, hololens, mrtk

I am a beginner using hololens1
I am developing a simple AR apps to detect a target image and display an object.
I am at a stage that I can successfully run the app on hololens and detect the image target and displaying the desired object. I am using unity 2019.4. Vuforia 9.8. MRTK.

However, I find out that the field of view that I can detect the target image is very limited (only a very limited space just in front of where I started the app). When I turn my head to somewhere else, even if I move the image target right in front of the camera, the object cannot be displayed. It shows in the log as extended tracking. I believe that there is some setting that limit the space where the augmented reality content can be displayed but I cannot figure which setting I need to adjust. Please advise. Thanks a lot

Expected to show augmented reality content whenever the image target is detected

Comment: There should not be any limit on where the augmented content can be seen. With the exception of the rendering camera frustum, but this should not be your case. Is your problem reproducible with an unmodified Vuforia sample?

Comment: As I am using hololens 1 . The vuforia sample for hololens 1 is no longer available.  I would be super grateful if anyone has a simple AR scene setup sample for hololens 1 for me to adapt 

Comment: I also suspect to ge the camera frustum but changing the field of view does not really help    How should I set the field of view of hololens1? Currently my setting :   Axis of FOV- vertical; field of view - 16. Clipping plane near 0.01. Far 1000